# How to execute python scripts from atom editor?

Tags: python

I am using atom editor. I use script package, atom runner package etc to execute python scripts, But when I am trying to execute tkinter(GUI) based scripts no output is shown. It just says successful. Now, Is there any way to execute python GUI scripts using atom?

Comment: Normally script with `tkinter` needs `root.mainloop()` at the end to run. IDLE use `tkinter` too so it runs own `root.mainloop()` and other `tkinter` scripts in IDLE can run without `root.mainloop()`. But you should always use `root.mainloop()`

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you friend.

Comment: @furas: It will be great you post your solution as an answer so as Madhu marks it as such in order to clear this question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally script with `tkinter` needs `root.mainloop()` at the end to run. `IDLE` use `tkinter` too so it runs own `root.mainloop()` and other `tkinter` scripts in `IDLE` can run without `root.mainloop()`. But you should always use `root.mainloop()`.